# Why use a ring buffer with data from sensor

Tags: c, queue, buffer, ring

I have a sensor that sends data at 8Khz to a microcontroller. The microcontroller parse the data and send it to the high level controler at 1Khz. I have seen people using ring buffer to collect the data from the sensor to the microcontroler and then take out the data to send it when we need.

If I receive 8 data but I can only send 1, the 7 other data in the ring buffer are useless...
I am curious why the use of a ring buffer is necessary/better compare to just wait for a new data and send it to the higher level?

Thank you

Comment: What size are the data from the sensor, and to the high level controller? And do you mean by "x kHz" (BTW, it's a lowercase "k" for kilo, and the unit is "Hz" in honor of Mr Hertz with an uppercase "H") the data rate?

Comment: Normally a so fast sensor is filtered. Standard approach is to have a ring buffer to avoid data incoming overflow, while retrieving enough samples for filtering. The filter can use samples at different sampling times lagging the current sample. Even a simple average will fetch samples up to s(-t).

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the data at 8 KHz rate and forwarding that data at 1 KHz rate, it means you get some data every 125 microseconds and you are forwarding it every 1 milliseconds.

Obviously you will need something to store that data every 125 microseconds and send the accumulated data after every 1 ms. For that you need some buffer kind of mechanism to store it. Hope this explanation helped.

Comment: And ring buffer is used for not overflowing the memory and taking the latest or oldest element depending on the configuration.